# For Oracle high availability on Azure Is Oracle Data Guard sufficient or is Active Data Guard (or Golden Gate) needed?

Tags: oracle, azure, high-availability, dataguard

According to Azure documentation, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn439773.aspx, Active Data Guard or Golden Gate are options for achieving high availability when running Oracle databases in Azure.

The cited benefits of ADG (reporting, backup offloading) are not priorities for our application. Will Oracle Data Guard do just as well for HA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle Active Data Guard is a licensed option introduced in version 11g. With Oracle Data Guard, you will have the same functionality in terms high availability. Switchover and failover will work the same way.

So the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both are good options for HA in azure.
each has advantages and disadvantages depending on your needs.

Oracle RAC is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an additional point, it should be noted that Active Data Guard also has a few key areas beyond the offloading of reporting apps, back-ups, and rolling upgrades.  One of which is the Auto Block Repair feature which is one of the big advantages of using the solution.  In a nutshell, using ADG will provide the ability for automated block repair in both directions between the primary and stand-by databases which provides a huge additional advantage.  I know the offloading features are also valuable, but this feature should not be undersold for the value for critical apps.